# Eclipse - should I clean the project before exporting an APK?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, apk

After several late-night debugging nightmares, I've somehow fallen into the paranoid habit of clicking 'Project -> Clean...' in Eclipse every time I'm about to export a signed/unsigned .APK for upload to an App Store.  I can only assume that, some time in the distant past, it seemed to be a necessary safeguard when debugging some external JAR or otherwise.

This adds several tedious minutes to the overall export process, particularly with multiple builds and/or apps.

Is this ever a necessary step, or just paranoia?

Comment: Personally, I think Clean+  Build is a good practice. Refer this: http://www.coderanch.com/t/528330/vc/Project-Clean-Eclipse

Comment: I never need to clean project before export APK in Eclipse ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaning the project recompile all of your classes and it may fix some problems that R.java class cause when resource id's have changed but already compiled classes that refrenced to those id's no longer exist or changed.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider a build system using Maven, Ant or the upcoming Gradle. This avoids problems with corrupt workspaces and lets you integrate automated testing easily; e.g. UnitTests or the simple question "Does it run on Android Version X.Y?"
I prefer Jenkins/Hudson as build server.

Especially when you have several apps for different targets, it can be cumbersome to run all the exports manually.

Ant based build system using Jenkins: [this](http://blackriver.to/2012/02/android-continuous-integration-with-ant-and-jenkins-part-1/) and [this](http://blackriver.to/2012/08/android-continuous-integration-with-ant-and-jenkins-part-2-2/) 
New Gradle based build system: [this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system)

Comment: Thanks for the information, it doesn't answer the question directly but it's very useful.